# OpenCV を用いた重心の求め方を知りたい

Tags: c++, opencv

顔の特徴点を検出するプログラムとして [Facemark:Facial Landmark Detection using opencv](https://www.learnopencv.com/facemark-facial-landmark-detection-using-opencv/) を参考にしており、そこから口だけ線で描かれるようにしました。

その際に、口の重心(中心)を求めたいのですがどうすればいいのか分かりません。
どのようにすればいいのか教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

OpenCVでは多角形のモーメントを求める[`cv::moments`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga556a180f43cab22649c23ada36a8a139)関数が提供されており、このモーメント(moments)から重心(mass center)も算出できます。

下記記事もご参考に：

- [OpenCV-Pythonチュートリアル OpenCVにおける輪郭(領域)](http://lang.sist.chukyo-u.ac.jp/classes/OpenCV/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html)
- [厳密な重心の求め方 | OpenCV画像解析入門](https://cvtech.cc/centroid/)

Answer (score 0):

数学的には 三角形の 重心の足し算の応用です。

求める 多角形の集合体を 基準点＋多角形の1辺 をつなぐ小さな三角形の集合体とみなして
右回りに外周の点を辿る場合、右回りに移動したら 足し算、左回りに移動したら引き算という
ふうにしてその重心の位置を計算します。

具体的には・・ あまり自信がないので ネットを探してみました。
数学的にちゃんと解説しているようなので
www5d.biglobe.ne.jp/~noocyte/Programming/Geometry/PolygonMoment-jp.html
を参考に実装してみてください。

Comment: また時間があったら詳しく書くかもしれません。